# Angular Material Input Floating Label Default Color Change

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6, angular-material-table

Can i change the floating default purple color of the lable?

```
 <mat-form-field>
 <input matInput placeholder="My Lable" formControlName="my-Lable">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer `<mat-label></mat-label>` than `*placeholder*`

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label>Agent Code</mat-label>
<input matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

then you just call it in css

```
mat-label {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

User color attribute of material theme:
color="primary" or "accent" or "warn",for extra colors you can use custom themes,or override color in css file.

```
 <mat-form-field color="accent"> <------here
   <input matInput placeholder="My Lable" formControlName="my-Lable">
 </mat-form-field>
```